# My code cause an debugging error (using dynamic array and the getline method), but I have no idea what part of my codecause this

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

manageFeatures(string input, string output, string commands) it seems that my code has some problems that cause debugging error. Debugging error message is :Exception thrown at 0x00EDDFF6 in project4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xDDDDDDDD. My code should read inputfile that 19 information is tap delimited in one line. I intended to read line by line, saving information to the "features" struct. Initial size of the array is 10. Whenever the full size is reached, it should double the size of the array.

```
ifstream in;
in.open(input);
ifstream com;
com.open(commands);
ofstream out;
out.open(commands);

int size = 10;
int count = 0;
string line;
features * array = new features[size];
while (getline(in, line))
{

    if (count == (size - 1))
    {
        features * temp = new features[size * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            *(temp + i) = *(array + i);
        }
        array = temp;
        size = size * 2;
        delete[] temp;
    }

    stringstream ssm(line);
    getline(ssm, array[count].geonameid, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].name, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].asciiname, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].alternatenames, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].latitude, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].longtitude, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].feature_class, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].feature_code, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].country_code, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].cc2, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].admin1_code, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].admin2_code, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].admin3_code, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].admin4_code, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].population, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].elevation, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].dem, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].timezone, '\t');
    getline(ssm, array[count].modification_date, '\t');
    count++;
}


out << "File: " << input << " Count: " << count << endl;



string command, id1, id2, name;
com >> command;
while (!com.fail())
{
    if (command == "find-id")
    {
        com >> id1;
        find_id(array, id1, out);
    }
    if (command == "find-name")
    {
        com >> name;
        find_name(array, name, out);
    }
    if (command == "distance")
    {
        com >> id1 >> id2;
        distance(array, id1, id2, out);
    }
    if (command == "radius")
    {

    }
    if (command == "more-info")
    {

    }
    com >> command;
}
```

Comment: since it's a **debug** error is it redundant to tell you to *debug* your program?

Comment: run your program through gdb and then you can see exactly where the error appears, the state of the system at that point and how you reached that point. Learn to use the debugger. It's tremendously helpful.

Comment: Since this is tagged C++, learn how to use std::vector< features > instead of fiddling with new and delete. That would already be one less source of potential problems with this code.